# How to compare the date of a product to actual date and count (WooCommerce/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I wanna to build a "NEW" badge that displays in the shop overview.
For that thing i need the date of a product from the product array.

for Example:

```
<?php 
$dateofproduct = get_the_date('Y-m-d'); 
$actualdate = current_time('Y-m-d');
?>
```

How can i do like:

When date is less than 4 weeks older from now on it gets the "NEW" Badge?

Comment: Google is not working in your country?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: got the actual date via current_time('Y-m-d'); but dont know how to compare it since they have other formats. current time brings "2016-11-14" and get the date gives me a format like "14. November 2016"

Comment: Alright, put the code and the description you've just made in your question. You could look at the php `strtotime()` function.

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`dateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) php object :

```
$prod_date = "05 September 2016";
$date_object = new DateTime();
$date_object->modify('-4 weeks');
$prod_is_new = (strtotime($prod_date) > strtotime($date_object->format('Y-m-d')));
var_dump($prod_is_new);
// output -> bool(false)

// and now : 
if ($prod_is_new) {
    ...
    // Stuff to add the new badge
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get something like this:

```
$dateofproduct = get_the_date('Y-m-d'); 
$actualdate = current_time('Y-m-d');

$time_compare = strtotime($dateofproduct);
$time_now = strtotime($actualdate);
$four_weeks = 4*7*24*60*60;
if($time_compare > ($time_now-$four_weeks)){
    //issue it NEW badge
}
```

*I hope it helps*